# How can I condense commands/actions/variables in Google Spreadsheet Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Forms and Sheets for my online trivia games. I've got the Sheets all decked out to do auto-scoring, and pass information from each individual sheet (1 for each round, 5 rounds) to a Master Scoresheet.

To save myself about 15 minutes a day, I figured I'd learn a little Google Scripting and write something that would clear all of the answers and validations from the day before with just one click.

And I succeeded! I'd never written anything in JavaScript before, but between reading explanations of commands on developer.google, and finding some incredibly helpful Stack Overflow answers, I was able to create a script that does EXACTLY what I need, with no issues at all! I just finished testing it about 5 minutes ago, and I'm still feeling stupidly proud!

BUT... I hate how spread out and lengthy it is. I haven't been able to figure this out. I don't know what to search for, or what to call it. Hoping someone in here will be willing to help me with this part!

I'll post the full code at the bottom, but for example - I create an 'lr' variable for each sheet - lr1, lr2, ... lr5. Then I make sure the value of the LR variable is greater than 1, and delete rows accordingly.

```
  if (lr1 > 1){
    scr1.deleteRows(2, lr1);
  };
  if (lr2 > 1){
    scr2.deleteRows(2, lr2);
  };
  if (lr3 > 1){
    scr3.deleteRows(2, lr3);
  };
  if (lr4 > 1){
    scr4.deleteRows(2, lr4);
  };
  if (lr5 > 1){
    scr5.deleteRows(2, lr5);
  };
```

But instead of having to spell each one out individually, I want to do something like this, which would do go through all 5 then stop:

```
  set %lrcount 1
  :ONE
  if %lr [ $+ [ %lrcount ] ] > 1 {                                     \\ if lr1 > 1
    scr [ $+ [ %lrcount ] $+ ] .deleteRows(2, %lr [ $+ [ %lrcount ] ]  \\ scr1.deleteRows(2, lr1)
    inc %lrcount 1                                                     \\ change 1 to 2(3, 4, 5)
    if %lrcount < 6 { GOTO ONE }                                       \\ 2(3, 4, 5) < 6, so repeat above
    else { unset %lrcount }                                            \\ 6 = 6, stop and move on
  }
```

Unfortunately, that's just a bastardized version of MSL. I don't know what the equivalent here would be. So, any help appreciated! Thank you!

Full Code:

```
function WipeAll() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET 1 ID");
  var scr1 = ss1.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lr1 = scr1.getLastRow();
  var sub1 = ss1.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl1 = sub1.getRange('A:Z');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET 2 ID");
  var scr2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lr2 = scr2.getLastRow();
  var sub2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl2 = sub2.getRange('A:Z');
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET 3 ID");
  var scr3 = ss3.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lr3 = scr3.getLastRow();
  var sub3 = ss3.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl3 = sub3.getRange('A:Z');
  var ss4 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET 4 ID");
  var scr4 = ss4.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lr4 = scr4.getLastRow();
  var sub4 = ss4.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl4 = sub4.getRange('A:Z');
  var ss5 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET 5 ID");
  var scr5 = ss5.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var lr5 = scr5.getLastRow();
  var sub5 = ss5.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl5 = sub5.getRange('A:Z');
  rl1.uncheck();
  rl2.uncheck();
  rl3.uncheck();
  rl4.uncheck();
  rl5.uncheck();
  if (lr1 > 1){
    scr1.deleteRows(2, lr1);
  };
  if (lr2 > 1){
    scr2.deleteRows(2, lr2);
  };
  if (lr3 > 1){
    scr3.deleteRows(2, lr3);
  };
  if (lr4 > 1){
    scr4.deleteRows(2, lr4);
  };
  if (lr5 > 1){
    scr5.deleteRows(2, lr5);
  };
};
```

**EDIT**:

If you check the comment on the answer provided by lamblichus, you'll notice an issue I had with run time. I was able to solve that by modifying it as such:

I think the issue here was the looping action kept having to reference the earlier variables. I assume there's some rate limiting happening server side. So instead of calling back over and over, I just built the names right into the loop (as they never change).

```
function WipeAll() {
  var spreadsheetIDs = ["", "", "", "", ""];
  spreadsheetIDs.forEach(spreadsheetID => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
    var scr = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var lr = scr.getLastRow();
    var sub = ss.getSheetByName('Answer Validator');
  var rl = sub.getRange('A:Z');
    rl.uncheck();
    if (lr > 1) scr.deleteRows(2, lr);
  });
};
```

Works great now, and is the same run time as the original long one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code involves a lot of repetition. You can simplify this a lot with a loop.

Since the only thing that changes is the spreadsheet ID, you can just declare an array with those IDs and loop through it, like this:

```
function WipeAll() {
  var spreadsheetIDs = ["SPREADSHEET_ID_1", "SPREADSHEET_ID_2", ...]; // Change to your actual spreadsheet IDs
  var sourceSheetName = "Form Responses 1";
  var subSheetName = "Answer Validator";
  var subRangeNotation = "A:Z";
  spreadsheetIDs.forEach(spreadsheetID => {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
    var scr = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
    var lr = scr.getLastRow();
    var sub = ss.getSheetByName(subSheetName);
    var rl = sub.getRange(subRangeNotation);
    rl.uncheck();
    if (lr > 1) src.deleteRows(2, lr);
  });
};
```

If the sheet names or the range notations were to change too, I'd suggest declaring an array of objects, similar to this:

```
var sourceData = [
  {
    spreadsheetId: "SPREADSHEET_ID_1",
    sourceSheetName: "Form Responses 1",
    subSheetName: "Answer Validator",
    subRangeNotation: "A:Z"
  },
  {
    // ... Other spreadsheets data ...
  }
];
```

#### Reference:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried your first suggestion and it works perfectly well and is most certainly MUCH smaller than my original, but it also takes a solid 45-60 seconds to run, where my original (lengthy) script finishes in about 15 seconds. This certainly isn't some horrible and insurmountable issue, I'm not going to be that picky, especially as this is still a significant reduction in the time I currently spend. Just curious why it would increase the time.

Comment: @SadBrontosaurus It shouldn't take significantly more time than the original script. Also, the execution time you're getting for both script is very long. It's not a complex script, it shouldn't take nowhere near that long.